# How to get the value of a textbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I can get the element like this `$("#name")` but I'm not sure how to get the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple, use the `val` method of jquery.

```
$('#name').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val)

```
$('#name').val();
```

The above is getter and to set, do the below:

```
$('#name').val('yourname');
```